# Compare data between two similar tables, different database

Tags: sql, database, compare, multiple-databases

We have this issue where there have been some changes made by someone to a database that we would like to change back. We have 2 copies of the database: a backup from a few days ago and their production database.

I'm trying to compare and get the records where Statecode from db1 != Statecode from db2. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried the following, but I think it's wrong:

```
SELECT fileId, statecode from DB1..fileBase t1
WHERE EXISTS    
(
    SELECT fileId, statecode from DB2..fileBase t2
    WHERE   t1.statecode = 0 AND
            t1.statecode != t2.statecode AND
            t1.ModifiedBy = '326AC533-DD41-E411-213C-03156D015A13'
)
```

EDIT Sample:

```
    Prod ID                                 Backup ID                      ProdStateCode BackupStateCode
    D4DEEA73-D5B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    D4DEEA73-D5B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    0          1
    621BD1FA-D1B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    621BD1FA-D1B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    0          0
    2E4E65F0-D1B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    2E4E65F0-D1B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    0          0
    35B8FCD9-D0B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    35B8FCD9-D0B6-E611-80E6-9216FEE69DCF    0          1
```

I want to get those that have Prod StateCode not equal to Backup State Code. I also tried

```
SELECT
  prod.fileId,
  prod.statecode
FROM DB1..fileBase AS prod
INNER JOIN DB2..fileBase AS back
  ON prod.fileId = back.fileId
WHERE prod.statecode != back.statecode
```

but the output doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are looking for and what you want to find.

Comment: Hi, I've added some sample. I just need the IDs where the State Codes do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** Use `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` for this as below it will give you the list of `field & statecode` where `field` is equal in both the tables but `statecode` that is not exist in the `db2` table

```
SELECT prod.fileId, prod.statecode 
FROM DB1.fileBase AS prod
LEFT JOIN DB2.fileBase AS back ON prod.fileId = back.fileId
    AND prod.statecode = back.statecode
WHERE back.statecode IS NULL
```

**OR**

```
SELECT prod.fileId, prod.statecode 
FROM DB1.fileBase AS prod
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM DB2.fileBase 
    WHERE prod.fileId = back.fileId--Only required if you wanna compare with statecode
    AND prod.statecode = back.statecode)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I used that along with some other WHERE clauses to properly extract the data required.